# Create a Task on Lead Conversion

Tags: workflow, tasks, lead-conversion

I have a workflow setup to create a task on lead conversion, However it does not seem to be firing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. For future reference if anybody faces this issue. The workflow rule was perfect though the settings in lead had to be modified.

Go to Customize>lead>settings>> Require Validation on Conversion>>True

[image]